# Keep form with dynamic fields and execute action on submit

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I have a form with some dynamic fields that I need to keep on screen (page) after clicking the submit button, the information entered by the user has to be appended to a file but the user may want to add more data of the same type, I don't know how to achieve this, I've been searching for a javascript way of doing it, but I'm really lost. I add the code of the files I have so far which are working.

So, in file1.php user can add up to 10 attribute fields to the form. In file2.php the user should fill the attributes fields in the form. On submitting, the data added by the user should be appended to a txt file and the form should stay displaying with the same fields for the user to add a new set of data if needed. I don't know if it is a good idea to direct form of file2.php to a file3.php.

So if you can advice me on what should I look for, I mean a clue on what should I try.

file1.php (the form where the user can add more fields to the form)

```
<?php
echo "<head>
<script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js' integrity='sha384-nvAa0+6Qg9clwYCGGPpDQLVpLNn0fRaROjHqs13t4Ggj3Ez50XnGQqc/r8MhnRDZ' crossorigin='anonymous'></script>
<script src='https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/dynamic-forms-fields/js/dynamic-form.js'></script>
</head>

<body>
<form action='file2.php' method='post'>
<br /><label for='subjectField'>Description</label>
<br /><input type='text' name='subjectField' size='60' value='Description of term' readonly />

<div id='dynamic_form'>
<input type='text' id='AttrName' name='AttrName' />: <input type='text' id='Attribute' name='Attribute' readonly /> 
<a href='javascript:void(0)' id='plus'> More</a> &nbsp; <a href='javascript:void(0)' id='minus'> Less</a>
</div>

<script>
var dynamic_form =  $('#dynamic_form').dynamicForm('#dynamic_form','#plus', '#minus', {
    // the maximum number of form fields
    limit: 10,
});
</script>
<br /><input type='submit' name='submit' id='submit' value='Create form' />
</form>";
?>
```

file2.php

```
<?php
$subjectField=$_POST['subjectField'];

echo "<form action='file3.php' method='post'>
<br><label for='subjectField'>Description</label>
<br /><input type='text' name='subjectField' size='60' value='$subjectField' readonly />";

forEach($attrib = $_POST['dynamic_form']['dynamic_form'] as $attrib) {
        echo "<br /><label for='Attribute'>".$attrib['AttrName'].": </label> <input type='text' id='".$attrib['AttrName']."' name='".$attrib['AttrName']."' size='40' placeholder='Attribute' required />";
}
echo "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Add' />
</form>
?>
```

Comment: I think you are probably wanting AJAX xmlHTTPrequest or the newer fetch, either of which will enable you to send and receive data without having a full page download there’s lots of info out there see eg [link] https://www.sitepoint.com/xmlhttprequest-vs-the-fetch-api-whats-best-for-ajax-in-2019/

Comment: Thanks, I will check it right now!